# Multi line ordinal chart in dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I am stuck on a problem here. Could be simple though but i am having a tough time figuring it out. I want to show multiple lines on a dc composite chart.
My data is like this:

```
{ Name: Mike, mark1: 26.9, mark2: 62.3 },
{ Name: John, mark1: 23.5, mark2: 60.3 },
{ Name: Firen, mark1: 24.3, mark2: 62.5 }
```

I need the name plotted against X axis and mark1 and mark2 plotted as lines against the Y axis. I found a fiddle here which uses a linear scale to achieve the same result. http://jsfiddle.net/anmolkoul/mzx6mnru/3/

But it uses a linear scale as the base dimension is numerical. My base dimension is a string and hence not working with the same code. I figured it is due to the scale definition that i am using. Here is the fiddle that i need help with: http://jsfiddle.net/anmolkoul/pjLoh1az/1/

I have currently defined my x axis as

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(nameDimension))
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```

I think this is where it is going wrong. I have two supplementary questions as well:

1. Once this is done, how to assign different colors to the lines ( it should reflect in the legend as well)
2. I was taking a look at the `dc.js` series chart, what does this line of code do?

`runDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return [+d.Expt, +d.Run]; });`

Does it pivot the two dimensions? or is it just a quicker way of creating two crossfilter dimensions.

Thank you for the help!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the ordinal values with :

`nameDimension.top(Infinity).map(function(d) {return d.Name}))`

which returns `["Mike", "John", "Firen"]` , then use it for the ordinal domain.

**But it's not necessary**, it's calculated automatically :

```
.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
```

For colors, you can use :

`dc.lineChart(lineChart1).group(mark1Group,"Mark 1").colors("#FF0000")`

Here is a fiddle with those modifications : http://jsfiddle.net/1exo25u9/

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the ordinal domain; it's calculated automatically.